# Using python selenium to click a ng-click button and upload a file

Tags: python, selenium

I am very new to python and selenium, but I need to use selenium to automatically upload some files.

There is a button I have to click, and it will pop a window in which I can select a file to upload.
And the HTML for this button is:

```
<button class="md-button md-default-theme" ng-transclude="" ng-show="excelshow" ng-click="selectFile()" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" style=""><span class="ng-scope">
                Excel upload
            </span><div class="md-ripple-container" style=""></div></button>
```

I have no idea how to click this button with selenium and upload the selected file.
I have tried to use `driver.find_element_by_class_name('md-button md-default-theme')` or `driver.find_element_by_css_selector`, but it doesn't work.
I think maybe I am using the `find_elements_by_css_selector` in a wrong way.

Thank you for your help!

---

EDIT:

The more complete content is here:

```
<md-toolbar style="background-color: white !important" class="md-default-theme">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <span>Manage Menu</span>
        <!-- fill up the space between left and right area -->
        <span flex=""></span>
        <!-- ngIf: isAuth --><div ng-if="isAuth" class="ng-scope">
            <input type="file" style="display:none" id="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upexecl(this)">
            <button class="md-button md-default-theme" ng-transclude="" ng-click="DownLoadS()" tabindex="0"><span class="ng-scope">
                Download Example
            </span></button>
            <button class="md-button md-default-theme" ng-transclude="" ng-show="excelshow" ng-click="selectFile()" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" style=""><span class="ng-scope">
                Excel upload
            </span></button>
            <button class="md-button md-default-theme" ng-transclude="" ng-show="offering" ng-click="onlineSave()" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="false" style=""><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">
                Save online
            </span></button>
            <button class="md-button md-default-theme ng-hide" ng-transclude="" ng-click="CancelEditSave()" ng-show="editshow" tabindex="0" aria-hidden="true"><span class="ng-binding ng-scope">
                Cancel edit
            </span></button>
        </div><!-- end ngIf: isAuth -->
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check if you have an hidden `input` of `type=file` in the your page. You can send the path of the excel file directly to the input, if the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

`md-button md-default-theme` is 2 class names: `md-button` & `md-default-theme`. .find_element_by_class_name() only takes a single parameter consisting of a single class name, e.g. .find_element_by_class_name("md-button"). That may or may not find the element you want based on whether that class name uniquely locates the element that you want.

Another option would be to use a CSS selector so that you can use all three classes in a single locator, e.g

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('md-button.md-default-theme')
```

where the . indicates a class name in CSS selector syntax.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry but it is still not works... I've posted the more complete content, thank you for your help!